# Cloning element finders

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

While researching available `ElementFinder` and `ElementArrayFinder` methods, I've noticed that there is a [`clone()` method](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.clone) which is briefly documented:

> Create a shallow copy of ElementFinder.

From what I understand, `clone()` is not coming from `WebdriverJS` and is a protractor-specific function. What I don't understand is *why would you want to clone an element finder or an element finder "array" in your tests*? What use cases does `clone()` cover?

---

I've looked into the [`protractor` source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=clone) to find example usages, but found only the [underlying change set](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/50f44f430851cbd76dbb3a41d6071198f6f479a4), which didn't help to have a clear picture.

Comment: It's not cloning the Element, it's cloning the ElementFinder

Comment: @IMSoP yeah, I agree, "fixed" the wording in the question. Good point, thanks.

Comment: So, clone() does work as of now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone was introduced here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1303.
And honestly now I think about it, it was a mistake to introduce it, as it offers no practical values.

Originally, there was fear that subsequent chains of elementFinders would affect previous ones:

```
var outerElement = element(by.abc...).all(by.def...).first().element(by.ghi...);
var outerText = outerElement.getText();
var innerElement = innerElement.element(by.xyz...);
// Now that I chained more things onto outerElement, is the original outerElement still behaving the same as before? (i.e. is outerText the same as outerElement.getText() still)
```