# Expect two elements to be equal

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to test if two elements in two different pages are equal. The reason for this is that I need to check a "copy" function that already works in my page, so both elements (divs in this case) have to be indentical:

I found that there's a method in protractor for element objects called "clone" but doesn't explains its purpose that much. Anyway I tried this:

```
// In the first page:
browser.get("/page1");
var clone1 = element(by.id("firstElem")).clone();

// then navigating to the other page
browser.get("/page2");
var clone2 = element(by.id("secondElem")).clone();

// then the expectation of them to be equal
expect(clone1).toEqual(clone2);
```

but the expectation fails with a very heavy stacktrace. Also tried comparing:

```
expect(clone1 == clone2).toBeTruthy();
```

which fails again.

- What is "clone()" supposed to be used for? and,
- How do I compare two divs in two separate pages for being identical?

Comment: Are those divs' markup supposed to be exactly equal?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by equal? Exactly the same html, down to whitespace and any orders of attributes or classes? Exactly the same text?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same html and same data. The case is that I'm using the same dynamic template to render what should be the same object but different user keys, so both users (owners of the same object) should present the same object in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is "clone()" supposed to be used for?

I've recently created a closely related question, you can follow the updates there:

- [Cloning element finders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929848/cloning-element-finders)

> How do I compare two divs in two separate pages for being identical?

Depending on your end goal, you may compare "outer HTML" representations of the elements using [`getOuterHtml()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getOuterHtml) , example:

```
browser.get("/page1");
element(by.id("firstElem")).getOuterHtml().then(function(value) {
    browser.get("/page2");
    expect(element(by.id("secondElem")).getOuterHtml()).toEqual(value);
});
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I can't fully understand what it does. What is getOuterHtml() for?. It says to retrieve the outer html but it is quite a poor description, can you elaborate about that?

Comment: @Cyberdelphos outer HTML is basically an HTML representation of an element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
expect(angular.equals(clone1, clone2).toBe(true));
```

Read more about angular.equals here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

Answer (score 0):

try without clone

```
browser.get("/page1");
var clone1 = element(by.id("firstElem"));

browser.get("/page2");
var clone2 = element(by.id("secondElem"));

expect(clone1).toEqual(clone2);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had already tried it and got same failing result